# Custom ranging in solr for custom field with websphere commerce

Tags: solr, websphere

I have customized the solar query so that it returns me the response in each fulfillment center for a particular product (say chair) as

inventory_11051======>10

inventory_11052======>0

etc

I need to add a filter in the front end so that my solar results are filtered to show only those products which has inventory greater than 0.

Please note: 11051 and 11052 are fulfillment ids which I should decide at run time and append to the filter. Can someone please help me on the same?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gathered from your question that you have a number of inventories you have to check? So you need to return fulfillment IDs for product X where inventory is greater than zero? I assume then that product ID plus fulfillment ID is the unique key for your index?

If so then filtering for inventory should not be a problem. Inventory is an integer, right? So to filter on inventory you would simply add " inventory:[1 TO *] " to your filter query parameter ("fq" if you're using the Solr web service). Filtering on fulfillment IDs should work similarly, except you won't be using a range: " fulfillment_id:(11051 OR 11052) ". Does that help? Remember to use a "+" before each filter if you have multiple filter params. So your filter query may look like this: "fq=+inventory:[1 TO *] +fulfillment_id:(11051 OR 11052)".

Comment: Thanks for the reply but inventory_11051 or inventory_11052 is one parameter which has an integer value. If i am shopping in a particular catalog, i would have either 11051 or 11052 at run time which i need to append to the filter for filtering out the products. Hope my question is clear based on this comment. I am just wondering if i could add this in the metadata after converting to UTF-8 format. If so, how should I do it?

Comment: Right, I figured that inventory_11051/11052 is one parameter. That is the fulfillment location, right? So your data might look like this:

product:"X",fulfillment_id:11051,inventory:20
product:"X",fulfillment_id:11052,inventory:6
product:"Y",fulfillment_id:11051,inventory:7

This can work as long as your unique key in Solr is a combination of product ID and fulfillment location.

Comment: Yeah you got it right. In my solar response, I have made modification so that if i query for a product, i get the inventory values in different fulfillment centers. I am wondering how I would add this custom parameter in the front end by adding in metadata so that it applies in the entire site instead of applying in each page separately.